# Swift cannot convert value of type 'Query' to expected argument type 'DocumentReference'

Tags: swift, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is, once the postTaskButton is tapped, copy the information from titleTextField to a new document in the "prtasks" collection and then copy it to the currently signed in user's personal document in the "users" collection.

To do so, I've tried execute a batched write once the 'PostTasks' Button is tapped. However, Xcode presents the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Query' to expected argument type 'DocumentReference'" for the line in bold.

```
    @IBAction func postTaskButton(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let title = titleTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let batch = db.batch()
    
    //Copy the information from the form to the 'prtasks' root collection
    let prtasksRef = db.collection("prtasks").document()
    batch.setData(["title" : title], forDocument: prtasksRef)
    
    //Copy the information from the form to a map entry in the user's personal tasks collection
    let userTasksRef = db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")
    **batch.setData(["title": title], forDocument: userTasksRef)**

    //Commit all of the above batch writes to the firestore
    batch.commit() { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            self.showAlert(for: "Error Writing Batch")
        } else {
            self.showAlert(for: "Batch write succeeded.")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore doesn't support the concept of update queries, where you send a condition and the data to update to the server. You can only write to a document when you know its exact/complete path.

This means you will have to:

1. Execute the query to get the matching documents.
2. Loop over the matching documents.
3. Update each document in turn (or in a batch).

---

Since I noticed that you're querying a collection called `users`: it is more common to store the profile documents by using the users UID as the document ID. By doing that you won't need to perform a query to update the user document, but can instead do something like:

```
let userDocRef = db.collection("users").doc(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
batch.setData(["title": title], forDocument: userDocRef)
```